# Multiple resources as one service hosted in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have multiple resources (database, App Service) hosted on Azure.  Currently they are on the free plan.  I'm looking to scale those subscriptions up but I think it will be better to have all those as one (let's say a VM).  Is that possible?

Comment: Not sure what, exactly, you're asking. VMs and web apps are two very different things. Maybe edit your question to be a bit clearer?

Comment: can I host web apps in a VM?

Comment: VMs can host whatever you want. But the actual 'web app' service of azure is something specific, and stands on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking to scale those subscriptions up but I think it will be better to have all those as one (let's say a VM). Is that possible?

As @David says, the VM could host whatever you want. But you need manage all the resource by yourself. For example, installed the IIS, database and host your web app.

If you just need host your web app and use azure database, I suggest you could use azure web app and azure database.

Since azure web app and database is fully managed compute platforms, you just need focus on the  business logic while Azure takes care of the infrastructure to keep your apps working well(We don't need installed the IIS and update the system version and so on).

Besides, azure have [resource group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview), we could easily manage all related resources in a group. (A container that holds related resources for an Azure solution. The resource group can include all the resources for the solution, or only those resources that you want to manage as a group. You decide how you want to allocate resources to resource groups based on what makes the most sense for your organization).